# QT Phonon on Windows 7

Tags: qt, windows-7, phonon

I have to say I'm kinda newbie with QT stuff.

I've tried to get to work Phonom using sample of code:

```
audioOutput = new Phonon::AudioOutput(Phonon::MusicCategory, this);
mediaObject = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
metaInformationResolver = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
Phonon::createPath(mediaObject, audioOutput);

mediaObject->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(":/sound/beep.wav"));
mediaObject->play();
```

The only warning that apears while compilation is: 
"WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect  Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName ) to  Phonon::AudioOutput ( no objectName ). " - it's results with no sound.

I tried to set device output by hand with no results. Meanwhile checked qmediaplayer example - which works fine.
Does anyone can tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

QT += phonon also included

Answer (score 0):

well first of all I'm not sure why you are calling create path() 2 times at line 3 and 5 with same arguments then i'll try setting source before connecting but i don't think this are the real problems

to me this worked:

```
Phonon::AudioOutput *audioOutput = new Phonon::AudioOutput();
Phonon::MediaObject *mediaObject = new Phonon::MediaObject();
mediaObject->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource("PathToFile"));
Phonon::createPath(mediaObject, audioOutput);
Phonon::MediaObject *metaInformationResolver = new Phonon::MediaObject();
mediaObject->play();
```

Comment: My mistake with c&p while fighting with examples. No positive result found.

Comment: Got it. After change 
Phonon::MediaSource(":/sound/beep.wav") to Phonon::MediaSource("C:\\Users\\offtza\\sound\\beep.wav") works fine.
Great thanks!